# How to get a particular value from the array in angularjs it can be used in js file itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, local-storage, login-control

```
$scope.login = function () {

    var userLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

    userLog = (userLogin.Name)
    console.log(userLogin);

}
```

this is in my browser localstorage

`[{" Name":"Admin","EmailId":"admin@gmail.com","password":"Admin","PhoneNo":"9765432108"},{"Name":"testuser2","EmailId":"testuser2@gmail.com","password":"testing","PhoneNo":9871324560},{"Name":"test11","EmailId":"test111@gmail.com","password":"test","PhoneNo":9632196321}]`

From the console i got the output as,

`0: Object { " Name": "Admin", EmailId: "admin@gmail.com", password: "Admin", … }`

​
but i want to that name and password field in the separate variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.login = function () {

```
        var userLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

        for (var i = 0; i < userLogin.length; i++) {

         console.log("EmailId: "userLogin[i].EmailId);
          console.log("password: " userLogin[i].password); 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code**

```
$scope.login = function () {

var userLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

for(data of userLogin){
    console.log(data.Name);
    console.log(data.password);
 }
```

}